# How can I resolve a modal inside another modal using Angular-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the angular-ui modal directive http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I want to call a different modal 'openEditModal' from my 'openAsideModal', how can I achieve this?

```
$scope.openAsideModal = function(){
  if($scope.asideInstance){
    $scope.asideInstance.close();
    delete $scope.asideInstance;
  }else{

    $scope.asideInstance = $aside.open({
      templateUrl: asideTemplateUrl,
      backdrop: false,
      controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, userEvents, openEditModal) {
        $scope.events = userEvents;
        $scope.openEditModal = function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        };
        $scope.ok = function(e) {
          $modalInstance.close();
          e.stopPropagation();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function(e) {
          $modalInstance.dismiss();
          e.stopPropagation();
        };
      },
      placement: 'right',
      size: 'sm',
      resolve:{
          userEvents: function() {
            // Return current user tasks
            return $filter('filter')($scope.events, {resourceId: currentUserId});
          },
          openEditModal: function() {
            return $scope.openEditModal;
          },
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: So what is the problem, just open it the same way you open the first one?

Comment: I'm getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error.